# Add path but also text above the path - D3js v3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

Trying to add the textual data above the path in this Zoomable Sunburst graph: [Zoomable Sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)
I have this code:

```
d3.json(jsonUrl, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(partition.nodes(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); 
        })
        .on("click", self.click)
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            //console.dir(d);
            return d.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value); 
        });
    });
```

But it doesn't work. No text is shown. I know it is something like that but I make something wrong. I am using D3js version 3 at the moment.

Some ideas?

Comment: try appending a textPath as a child of the "text" element. put the .text on the textPath element.

Comment: Besides Robert Longson's answer disguised as a comment, you have to know what elements can be parents and what elements can be children. You **cannot** append a text to a path. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2537/core-svg-concepts-used-in-d3-js-visualization/17339/correctly-appending-an-svg-element#t=201612151331295707414

Comment: Tried .append("text").append("textPath").text(/*get text for the path*/) and it puts the <text> tag with subtag <textPath> inside the <path> tag which of course doesn't work. i don't see the text though it is visible in Firebug in the html section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found this [Donut Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) example and changed some parts in my code.
Though it looks cluttered it does the job. Maybe with some polishing I could get decent looks:

[image: Zoomable sunburst with text]

Here is my code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")"),
g = null;

d3.json(dataFile, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(partition.nodes(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); 
        })
        .on("click", self.click);

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { 
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) { 
            return d.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value);
        });
});
```